# symlink all shebangs in node_modules/.bin to current folder

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to symlink all shebang scripts in `./node_modules/.bin/` folder and I have tried this:

`ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/* ./ && ls -l ./`

but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not appear to be working"? No symlink is created? Not all symlinks created? Error message? Nonzero exit code? No output?

What does `echo ./node_modules/.bin/*` print?
What is the exit code of `ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/* ./`?
Which file system do you use?

Comment: yes, no symlinks

Comment: Do the name of those files start with `.`? Again, what does `echo ./node_modules/.bin/*` or `ls -lA ./node_modules/.bin` print? Please add the clarifications to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I know what you're asking, but I don't want to make assumptions that turn out to be false. So here they are --- please correct them as appropriate.

- I'm assuming that every file in `./node_modules/.bin/`is a Shebang file. There is no need to check file extensions, let alone opening each file and checking if it starts with a shebang.

Given this assumption, my first shot at your problem would be a shell loop like the following:

```
for SCRIPT in ./node_modules/.bin/* ; do
    BN=$(basename "$SCRIPT")
    ln -s "$SCRIPT" "$BN"
done
```

Hope that works for you, give or take a typo or two.

EDIT: Thanks for accepting my answer,  but user  Stéphane Chazelas's criticism is well-taken. While I successfully  tested the loop on a directory full of scripts (from an empty directory), he's right to note that it may fail on other occasions, and that the loop doesn't actually improve on a simple `ln -s ./node_modules/.bin/* ./`

Comment: It is actually worse than the OP's attempt. Because you forgot a few quotes but also because if there are directories named like the basename of some of those scripts in the current directory, that will create the symlinks in those directories instead of reporting an error (and there's the usual problem with command substitution and trailing newline characters). `ln -s foo/bar .` actually does a `ln -s foo/bar ./bar`

Comment: Before asking for clarification I tested that a command similar to the one in the original question actually creates symlinks for all files. It is still unclear why the command did not work in the original poster's environment. If the for loop works while the original command does not it would be interesting to find out the reason and improve the command. As Stéphane Chazelas already wrote, the loop has more problems than the original command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Fair points, and I edited my post to acknowlege iit. For some reason, the OP's simple ln -ls didn't work for me when I first tried it, and the loop did. Now it does. I suppose I made some other mistake somewhere.

Comment: That's mystifying to me as well, @Bodo!